Get all H2 elements from a page with Selenium
Following from my previous two questions: does Selenium have something like BeautifulSoup's Find All?
I need to get all the content of H2 tags in a page like this one.
The great code JeffC brought in the previous questions gets the content of one specific tag for each page. But here I have up to 20 similar tags for each page.
Also, I need to get both the text of the H2 and the HREF.
Current state:
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = 'http://www.biblioteca.presidencia.gov.br/presidencia/ex-presidentes/jose-sarney/discursos/1985?b_start:int=0'
driver.get(url)
h2 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "tileHeadline"))).text
print(h2)

So far, the code brings only the first element in each page. Should I change specifications within the EC element?

I know you've already accepted an answer but it didn't actually explain what the issue was. The main issue is that
single_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located())
                                                   ^ singular element

returns a single element. There is a plural version of it that returns a collection of elements,
element_collection = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located())
                                                            ^ plural elementS

Using this info, we can update your current code,
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = 'http://www.biblioteca.presidencia.gov.br/presidencia/ex-presidentes/jose-sarney/discursos/1985?b_start:int=0'
driver.get(url)
links = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2 a")))
for link in links:
    print(link.text)
    print(link.get_attribute("href"))

which outputs
15 de março de 1985 - Pronunciamento do Presidente José Sarney, no exercício da Presidência da República, ao empossar o ministério
http://www.biblioteca.presidencia.gov.br/presidencia/ex-presidentes/jose-sarney/discursos/1985/01.pdf/view
17 de março de 1985 - Pronunciamento da Presidente José Sarney, no exercício da Presidência da república, por ocasião da abertura da primeira reunião do ministério da nova República
http://www.biblioteca.presidencia.gov.br/presidencia/ex-presidentes/jose-sarney/discursos/1985/02.pdf/view
...


Also, please don't use locators like
.find_elements("css selector", "h2 a")

where "css selector", etc. is a string. Yes, it will work but it's prone to typos and your IDE won't know about the typos until you run the script and it fails. Instead use By.CSS_SELECTOR as below
.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2 a")

Your IDE will help you autocomplete it and if there are typos, the IDE will flag them as errors before you run it saving you time.

This script gets the h2 a elements, the href, the text, and then prints those:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation", "enable-logging"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
try:
    driver.get("http://www.biblioteca.presidencia.gov.br/presidencia/ex-presidentes/jose-sarney/discursos/1985?b_start:int=0")
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(("css selector", ".tileHeadline")))
    elements = driver.find_elements("css selector", "h2 a")
    for element in elements:
        print()
        print(element.get_attribute("href"))
        print(element.text)
finally:
    driver.quit()

The first few lines of output:
http://www.biblioteca.presidencia.gov.br/presidencia/ex-presidentes/jose-sarney/discursos/1985/01.pdf/view
15 de março de 1985 - Pronunciamento do Presidente José Sarney, no exercício da Presidência da República, ao empossar o ministério

http://www.biblioteca.presidencia.gov.br/presidencia/ex-presidentes/jose-sarney/discursos/1985/02.pdf/view
17 de março de 1985 - Pronunciamento da Presidente José Sarney, no exercício da Presidência da república, por ocasião da abertura da primeira reunião do ministério da nova República

http://www.biblioteca.presidencia.gov.br/presidencia/ex-presidentes/jose-sarney/discursos/1985/28%20de%20marco%20de%201985/view
28 de março de 1985 - Pronunciamento do Presidente José Sarney, no exercício da Presidência da República, ao receber a bancada do PMDB no Rio de Janeiro

